# Is it possible to run XAMPP's fake sendmail MTA as a daemon and thus as a standalone MTA?

Tags: php, xampp, sendmail, mta, sendmail.exe

I want to send mails via XAMPP/PHP. Now I just found that the sendmail.exe delivered with XAMPP only seems to be a fake sendmail. I'm wondering if it can act as a full MTA, so can I run it as a daemon on 0.0.0.0:25 and send mails through sendmail.exe or is it not capable of doing that?

I know how to send mails via PHP/sendmail to my GMAIL MTA, but I don't want to use GMAIL or others, I want to run my own mailserver, is that possible with the XAMPP packagem don't think so right?

Comment: I've just found an answer to my own question, which is explained in this link: http://glob.com.au/sendmail/

Obviously, it's not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Ian, using a local MTA is a bad idea if you have a dynamic IP address. Mail would be rejected from most reliable email systems (gmail, hotmail etc).

If you still want to persist, I suggest using [hmailserver](http://www.hmailserver.com/).